# “Comparing” vs “A comparison of ”

Tags: word-choice, nouns, gerunds

A professor criticized the language in a presentation. In particular he said that English preferred a noun phrase such as *a comparison of*  to a gerund such as *comparing*.

For reference the entire sentence follows.

> Comparing prominent symptoms in drug addiction with models of aberrant learning may help us understand how those symptoms arise

I have seen both forms used in the technical literature but his point was more one of general usage. I don’t intend to argue the point with him. I merely want to know if his point is more than one of personal preference.

Comment: Maybe he didn’t like that one *-ing* was a verb phrase and the other an actual noun.

Comment: I'd say that professor should stick to his specialist subject matter (drug addiction or whatever), and not waste the students' time promoting his own idiosyncratic linguistic preferences.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers: Some professors confuse mimicry with progress. The grumblings of another bedeviled graduate student aside, it's nice to know that I wasn't writing poor English even his would have been, at best, a minute point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, the meaning is the same, and neither seems particularly awkward or confusing. I'd say it's personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a large element of personal preference in his comment, but I think his preference is justified.

Subjects and objects should, really, be nouns. While you often see "A gerund is a noun" written in amateur grammar sites, a gerund is not a noun. If it were, we would call it a noun and save a lot of confusion.

A gerund is a [verbal noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_noun), with characteristics of both noun and verb. It is the verbal characteristics that make is less suitable to be the subject or object of a sentence. Using the noun phrase makes it clear that you are referencing the concrete existence of a comparison, rather than the idea of an occurrence of comparing.

I am not suggesting the gerund is wrong, just that the noun phrase is arguably more elegant.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought gerunds were on an equal footing with other nouns and did not catch that they retained , shall we say, "verbish impurities".

Comment: Why do you say ‘Subjects and objects should, really, be nouns’? You have yourself used not nouns, but clauses, as the subjects and objects in several of your sentences.

Comment: ...because it is a lot easier to type than 'noun, noun clause, or noun phrase', and because mac389 doesn't strike me as the kind of person who needs it spelling out.

Comment: I appreciate the compliment @RoaringFish.

Comment: Yet your link to Wikipedia starts out with "In linguistics, a verbal noun is a noun...."

Comment: And the rest of that first sentence? "...formed from or otherwise corresponding to a verb."  You can learn about the verbal characteristics of a gerund here: [Double nature of the gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Double_nature_of_the_gerund)

Comment: @RoaringFish The rest of the sentence is irrelevant.  The sentence states a verbal noun is a noun.  A noun formed in a certain way, certainly, but a noun nonetheless.  Or do you believe that a sentence of the form "X is a Y formed from ..." means X is *not* a Y?

Comment: An elephant is a grey animal. That does not mean'grey animal' and 'elephant' mean the same thing, it just means that 'elephant' belongs to the group 'grey animal'. The rest of the sentence is relevant because it encapsulates how a verbal noun is different from other nouns. The word 'verbal' is not there because it looks nice. It is there for a very good reason, as the link I supplied previously shows. You should click on it and read it, and you are welcome to ask me if you have problems with it.

Comment: @RoaringFish Thanks for the lesson on the elephant.  If you say "a gerund is a verbal noun" and "a verbal noun is a noun...", then that means a gerund is a noun.  Also, just because a verbal noun is different from other kinds of nouns does not mean it is not a noun (incidentally, it's a bit ironic that you say "*other* nouns").

Comment: You should explain what about your link suggests a gerund is not a noun.  Believe it or not, I did read it before.  I suspect you think that a noun cannot have verbal properties, but that's nowhere in the definition of a noun.

Comment: A verbal noun can take an object, be modified by an adverb, and show distinctions of aspect and voice. If, as you insist, a verbal noun is just a noun by another name, then you should be able to show me a noun - 'car', for example - taking an object, being modified by an adverb, and having distinctions of voice and aspect.  I am also interested in what 'verbal properties' the word 'car' has.

Comment: Neither of the claims "a gerund is a verbal noun" and "a verbal noun is a noun" require me to show every noun is a verbal noun.  The first claim just means that 'gerund' belongs to the group 'verbal noun' and the second claim just means that 'verbal noun' belongs to the group 'noun'.  Together they imply that 'gerund' belongs to the group 'noun'.  This does not mean gerunds and nouns are the same thing.  In particular, this does not mean a given noun such as 'car' is a gerund.  Neither can you conclude that 'car' is a verbal noun.